# pygame.quit(), quit(), or run = False?

Tags: python, pygame, exit

Lets says I just have a normal game loop using pygame.

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

pygame.quit()
```

Where `run = False` is, should I use `run = False` and `pygame.quit()` at the end? Should I just put `pygame.quit()` where `run = False` is? Should I use `quit()` without `pygame` in front of it at all? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to do it exactly as you do it in the question.

[`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) uninitialize all pygame modules. Any further call to a pygame module (except `pygame.init()`) will cause an exception. To terminate a pygame application correctly, `pygame.quit()` has to be the called at the end. If you do `pygame.quit()` in the main application loop, then the application will crash if you do something after it (e.g. `pygame.disaply.update()`).